APS/Forge viewer not initialising correctly until home button is pressed
When we load models into our viewer, recently user have complained that the initial load doesn't work correct. as you can see from the image below.

once you press the house button the view cube then loads and the model appears straight away, has any experienced this behaviour ?


It looks like a large model. User have to wait till GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT is fired. The user may be clicking on the home button before the geometry is fully loaded.
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
   // Geometry loaded.
});    

